# Epson L375 setup Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: printing, 18.04, epson

I have just installed Ubuntu 18.04 to a Toshiba satellite, works great.

I am a medium user and I want to know how to install an Epson L375 printer.

The printer was already working nicely to all our windows devices. Please help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

so to look for linux drivers on Epson, one starts here http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/?OSC=LX and entering L375 takes one to here http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/du/02/DriverDownloadInfo.do?LG2=EN&CN2=&DSCMI=71623&DSCCHK=e1fdb812f3b09b3da605fd49ef90a9e43b62db49

click the ACCEPT button and it lists the options; if you have 64bit Ubuntu you should click to download **epson-inkjet-printer-escpr_1.6.20-1lsb3.2_amd64.deb**

If you select **OPEN** when you click to download, the OPEN should mean **gdebi installer** installs the package for you then;

if instead you select **SAVE**, you need to open your **Downloads** folder; and double-click on this package; that should trigger an install; that should also trigger a configure in the linux printing

Answer (score 0):

The L375 Epson driver is an ESC/P-R Driver (generic driver).

you need the driver used by the L365 Epson Printer that gets all the features of this printer, the file is **epson-printer-utility_1.0.2-1lsb3.2_amd64.deb**.

You will need to install the **lsb-*** packages to install this in Ubuntu 18.04.